# Random jquery datatables routing issue in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I use datatables within my Ruby on Rails app, and lately I've just started randomly getting this error message, and I'm not quite sure sure why.

Here's the message:

```
Started GET "/assets/images/sort_asc.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-19 23:12:48 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/sort_asc.png"):
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (7.4ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (80.3ms)
```

Here's what my application.js and application.css files look like:

```
#application.js
/ This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

.

```
#application.css
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 */
```

Any idea why I'm getting this? The actual files are there (I just placed them manually, but I'm not sure what else I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the line before the require tree in application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

Comment: Thanks. I did that but still getting the error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Put its also *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables above the  *= require_tree .

Comment: Got it working. I removed what I already had and followed the steps on the jquery-datatables-rails github page that mentioned to run this: "rails generate jquery:datatables:install bootstrap3". It's pretty much the exact same thing as putting them in manually, but it looks like it puts them in the right spot. So good to go here!

Answer (score 0):

In your css manifest, put `*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables` before `*= require_tree .`